# Hosting Angular 1.5 Component in a Bootstrap 3 popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular 1.5 Component that works fine on a vanilla HTML page, but when I try to embed it in a Bootstrap popover, it sort-of-only-but-not quite works.

The component does a little keyboard interception and filtering of keypresses, hooks into the model's formatting chain and uses a couple of other services and directives, but nothing too "funky".

The `total` and `values[]` attributes are passed through the scope, but while `total` displays, the `values` don't but the component does not how many entries there are in the `values` array. Nothing obvious is dumped out in the console.

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this one.

Code is available: https://github.com/jeffeld/bf-calculator.git

Clone, `npm install` and `gulp default` will build it. Test code is in index.html.

Many thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Nobody wants to search through a whole repository. Regarding "not sure where to start: write unit tests for the most important components first.

Comment: The repo is a complete and verifiable example. It's too big for a fiddle/plunker and the code is ES6/Babel so needs transpiling for various browers.

As for "I'm not sure where to start..." there are unit tests. Perhaps I should be more clear: Having pretty good Angular and Bootstrap knowledge (I do them both for a living), I've not seen this sort of issue before. Having exhausted my knowledge, and having Googled etc. I can't find any pointers. How do you start troubleshooting this sort of issue, once you've covered the obvious?

Comment: You could at least take a stab at showing what you think is the relevant code. You're giving us a link, and then we have to guess what files the relevant source code might be in.

Comment: ~410 LOC + HTML is not an MCVE.